# When I render the scene, the dress gets weird

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

I don't even know whats going right now. So im just going to post an image hoping someone can help me lol. 
The Left is before render and the right is after render.
P.S. when is (Shift-Z render its fine, but when I F12 render the image or animation this error happens) 
Can someone help explain to me why the dress is doing that when its rendered??[image]

Comment: "*So im just going to post an image hoping someone can help me lol*" Nah, we aren't about to play a guessing game, so you better post some info about your scene setup, otherwise this would be a shot in the dark

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, figured it out. (It only took me like 50+ legit hours) 
I had the displacement modifier turned off. Simple solution.